# How to shift/change timestamp in a scheduled rule?

Tags: rules

A scheduled rule was triggered. Is it possible to change a date of the scheduled action? (programmatically or not) For example, the scheduled action will be triggered in 3 days but then you would like to change it for 1 day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the timestamp of when the task is to be scheduled is stored in `rules_scheduler` db table, in `date` field. You can run a query like:

```
db_update('rules_scheduler')
  ->expression('date', 'date + 86400') // 86400 = 24 * 60 * 60
  ->condition('tid', $your_task_id)
  ->execute();
```

Comment: I have a question. Is $your_task_id  equal to tid in this case?

Comment: Yes, this query will update the task which has tid equal to $your_task_id